# Send async emails in django 3.0

Tags: python, django, email, asynchronous, django-3.0

I've seen that django has recently added [asynchronous support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/async/) in version 3.0. However, the docs are not completely clear for me and they do not provide a working example.

Is it possible to send an email asynchronously using `django.core.mail.send_mail` and `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async`? If so, how would this be accomplished?

Thanks beforehand